# How to implement noise processes for RODE in Julia?

Tags: julia, differential-equations, noise

I'm trying to implement a RODE in Julia:

du/dt = [W[1] + W[2]]*u(t)

where W[1] is a random compex valued Gaussian field and W[2] is a real noise term.

I think the RODEProblemsolver can solve such problems

```
function f(du, u, p, t, W)
    du .= u * (W[1] + W[2])
end

prob = RODEProblem(f, u0, tspan, p)
sol = solve(prob, RandomEM(), dt = dt )
```

I have to define W first, because I do not want Gaussian white noise (default).
I also cannot find the desired process in the DiffEqNoiseProcess library.
What do I need to define W propertly?

My second question for the problem:
How can I store W[1] and let RODE generate different solutions for fixed W[1] and varying W[2]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need to define W properly?

It depends. You can use one of the `AbstractNoiseProcess` types described here:

https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqNoiseProcess/stable/abstract_noise_processes/

For example, if the best way to describe your noise is by a grid of values, then use `NoiseGrid`. Or with a function `f(W,t)` then use `NoiseFunction`. Etc. And when you have the noise process, just pass it in `prob = RODEProblem(f, u0, tspan, p, noise = mynoiseprocess)`

> My second question for the problem: How can I store W[1] and let RODE generate different solutions for fixed W[1] and varying W[2]?

Easiest way to do this might be with `NoiseFunction`, depending on the way W[2] is generated.

Comment: Thank you, I implemented the noise process! However, I couldn't pass it correctly into the RODEProblem. What is the correct syntax?And is it the same for SDEProblem? In SDEProblem, I defined two different stochastic parts using du[i: j], which worked, but I also have trouble passing the noise processes correctly to the problem.

Comment: In SDEProblem `du[i,j]` is referring to the `g` matrix. In RODEProblem, you just get `W[1]` and `W[2]` in the `f`.

Comment: The f (and g) matrices are implemented correctly (I tried both methods with just 1 noise). What I meant was that I don't know how to pass more than 1 noise process to `prob = RODEProblem(f, u0, tspan, p, noise = mynoiseprocess)`. For example I tried as tuple or array (`mynoiseprocess =(W1, W2)` / `mynoiseprocess = [W1, W2]` )

Comment: No, it should be a single noise process which is an array of length 2.

Comment: If I try that, I get the error `type Array has no field dW`

Comment: It sounds like you defined two noise processes instead of one?

Comment: The equation I should implement looks like du/dt = [alpha(t) + beta(t)]*u(t). alpha(t) is a OU Process and I defined beta(t) with NoiseGrid. The RODE gets solved when passing W = alpha(t) or W = beta(t). But it fails, when I want the two different processes in the same RODE. 
I think I misunderstood the meaning of W[i]. It is the same process, just takes the i-th component of the vector .. 
But how can I implement the original problem with the noise processes alpha(t) and beta(t) then?

Comment: This might be easier to discuss on https://discourse.julialang.org/